# Valid HTTP request

Tags: python, sockets, http

I'm making a program in python to get html from an url using an http request. I tried this using a page on a testwebserver I made for this, and it worked with this request:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 8080))
s.send(("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080").encode("utf8"))

x = s.recv(1024)
while not x:
    x = s.recv(1024)

print(x.decode("utf8"))
```

But when I try it on another site, it says bad request. How would I make this http valid for each site?
And how would I add get and post values in this?

Comment: Why in the world would you try to create the HTTP protocol from scratch on a raw socket? Use an HTTP library such as [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: HTTP is a standard. You are clearly violating the standard. That's why you get "bad request". Specifically you are missing a `\r\n\r\n` at the end in this particular case. But HTTP is way more complex than this and then there is also HTTPS and and .. . If you really want to implement everything by your own then please study [the standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) first. If you just want to make a request though simply use a library which handles this complexity already.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is

```html
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
print (r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I add get or post values to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying avoid pip packages, you can still do http request nicely with standard library.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
print(urlopen('http://localhost:8080').read())
```

I think it's possible with the way you are doing. You might need another header for the particular site, but I can't tell if you don't provide us the website. But implementing http client in python is like reinventing a wheel.